# How do I use Nuke.Build to apply .yml files to a local kubernetes cluster (docker desktop)?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core, docker-desktop, nuke-build

I am trying to create a Target in Nuke that will apply a .yml file to my local Kubernetes instance (the one that comes with Docker Desktop).

I can see that there are CLI task classes for Kubernetes as they're listed here (under the exhaustive list of supported tools): https://nuke.build/docs/common/cli-tools/

But I can't find any examples of how to use those methods.
How do I use them? *Are* there any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out with a lot of trial and error.

```
Target ApplySomething => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            KubernetesApply(_ => _
                .AddFilename("C:\\full-path\\your-deployment.yml")
            );
        });
```